# Tracing a specialized template object's enum member value

Tags: c++, enums, template-specialization

I have a struct template with an enum value recursively defined as follows:

```
template <unsigned x, unsigned y>
struct Special
{
  enum { value = x * Special<x-1, y-1> :: value; }
};

template <unsigned n>
struct Special<n, 0>
{
  enum { value = 1; }
};
```

I wanted to know the gradual growth of **value** for an instance of **Special** like:

```
Special <8, 3> spl;
```

So, I inserted the following constructor inside the generic struct definition:

```
Special() { cout << "Value, x and y are: " << value << "," << x << "," << y;}
```

But, I only got the final values printed as 336, 8, 3. How do I get the full picture of gradual reduction in y from 3 to 0?

Comment: Grab a piece of paper. On the first line you write `value = 8 * Special<7, 2>::value`. On the next line you write `value = 7 * Special<6, 1>::value` and so on. Then when you get to the last line (when `y` is zero and `value` is `1`) then you go back up and uses the results from the line before to finish the equations.

Comment: ...and then make it a `static constexpr int` member, or even better, a function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: So, when you were asked to write a program to find the result of 98 * 999, you grabbed a piece of paper, wrote 98 in the first line, 98 in the second line, ......98 in the 999th line and vertically added them up, right? Who said that nerds lack humour?

Comment: You said you wanted to *trace* the result, yes? Not just *calculate* the end result?

Comment: Conceded and still enjoying a conjured up image of where your tongue is pointing to, when you made this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, I only got the final values printed as 336, 8, 3. How do I get the full picture of gradual reduction in y from 3 to 0?

You don't get the expected output since the classes themselves don't recursively derive from themselves. When you construct a `Special<8,3>`, it is not a derived from `Special<7,2>`. Hence, the constructor of `Special<7,2>` does not get called  when you construct a `Special<8,3>`.

**Solution 1: Change the class to inherit from the next recursive class**

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned x, unsigned y> struct Special;

template <unsigned x, unsigned y> 
struct Special : Special<x-1, y-1>
{
   Special()
   {
      std::cout << "Value, x and y are: " << value << "," << x << "," << y << std::endl;
   }
   enum { value = x * Special<x-1, y-1> :: value };
};

template <unsigned n>
struct Special<n, 0>
{
   Special()
   {
      std::cout << "Value, x and y are: " << value << "," << n << "," << 0 << std::endl;
   }

   enum { value = 1 };
};

int main()
{
   Special<8,3> s;
}
```

**Solution 2: Use a recursive function to get the value instead of an enum**

Another way to get the required output would be through a recursive function call instead of `enum` in the class and have the code to produce the output in the functions.

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned x, unsigned y>
struct Special
{
   Special() { getValue(); }

   static int getValue()
   {
      int value = x*Special<x-1, y-1>::getValue();
      std::cout << "Value, x and y are: " << value << "," << x << "," << y << std::endl;
      return value;
   }
};

template <unsigned n>
struct Special<n, 0>
{
   static int getValue()
   {
      int value = 1;
      std::cout << "Value, x and y are: " << value << "," << n << "," << 0 << std::endl;
      return value;
   }
};

int main()
{
   Special<8,3> s;
}
```

Output in both cases:

```
Value, x and y are: 1,5,0
Value, x and y are: 6,6,1
Value, x and y are: 42,7,2
Value, x and y are: 336,8,3
```

Comment: _When you construct a Special<8,3>, it is not a derived from Special<7,2>_ is new testament for me. Thanks.